# Hard disk space - find growing folders

Tags: disk-usage

I am having persistent disk space trouble with my /root partition on a Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon, 4.6.7 on a 5.4.0-45-generic kernel.

Initially, I assigned too little space my /root, assuming the OS can use space on the much bigger main partition. As now my /root keeps filling up without me using any additional space or installing new programs, this must be due to all kinds of temporary files clogging up space.

I already used [web-lists](https://miloserdov.org/?p=3471) of things that might be culprits and wrote me an automated cleaning script. But it seems this time I am out of luck and something else, yet, just filled my disk space.

I'd love for this issue to be resolved once and for all, hence I need to know which folders exploded recently in size. I guess there would be a way to do this by tracking timestamps and sizes of recently created files, in a global search, but that's out of my league for bash-fu.
Obviously the disk analyzer tool is useless for this, as it doesn't tell me what folder is the culprit for this tumourous growth, only what the current state of the disk is.

Comment: Run `sudo du /root | sort -n -r | head -n 20` periodically to see the top 20 root folders by size. I know it's not exactly what you're looking for but may help.

Comment: What resides on your `/boot` other than kernel images?

Comment: @Panki All my programs were put there (in /root, not /root/boot) by Mint by default. No idea how to change that. Telling it to not use /boot for everything would also be a solution to the problem.

Comment: 1) The `du` recommended by @AnthonyKelly should include option `-x`.  2) You might also benefit from adding `-S` (try both ways).  3) I assume you are talking about the "root" partition, mounted at `/`.  4) `/var/log` and `/var/cache` are obvious possible culprits.

Comment: @DavidG. thanks, but I'm done in my life chasing culprits. I want a nuke option that does it automatically. I never ever again want to have to google for a million subfolders whether it's safe to delete those on linux.

Comment: Then your obvious choice is to enlarge the partition.  Can be easy or hard, depending on how you've done things.  (If you don't have lvm in place, I would boot from a live media and use `gparted`.  Expect it to take some time [hours or more].)   The method having found the "culprits" is to mount something else, like a directory of the main partition, on the problematic directory.  Or maybe just symlink it.